# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'c_name' on table 't_name' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, cascade

I have a database table called `Lesson`:
**columns:** `[LessonID, LessonNumber, Description]` ...plus some other columns

I have another table called `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection`:
**columns:** `[LessonID,NextLessonID_1,NextLessonID_2,NextLessonID_3]`

When a lesson is completed, its LessonID is looked up in the `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection` table to get the three possible next lessons, each of which are associated with a particular range of scores.  If the score was 0-33, the LessonID stored in NextLessonID_1 would be used.  If the score was 34-66, the LessonID stored in NextLessonID_2 would be used, and so on.

I want to constrain all the columns in the `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection` table with foreign keys referencing the LessonID column in the lesson table, since every value in the `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection` table must have an entry in the LessonID column of the Lesson table.  I also want cascade updates turned on, so that if a LessonID changes in the Lesson table, all references to it in the `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection` table get updated.

This particular cascade update seems like a very straightforward, one-way update, but when I try to apply a foreign key constraint to each field in the `Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection` table referencing the LessonID field in the Lesson table, I get the error:

***Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'c_name' on table '`Lesson_ScoreBasedSelection`' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths.***

Can anyone explain why I'm getting this error or how I can achieve the constraints and cascading updating I described?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the SQL Server constraint on this, why don't you solve this problem by creating a table with SelectionID (PK), LessonID, Next_LessonID, QualifyingScore as the columns.  Use a constraint to ensure LessonID and QualifyingScore are unique.

In the QualifyingScore column, I'd use a tinyint, and make it 0, 1, or 2.  That, or you could do a QualifyingMinScore and QualifyingMaxScore column so you could say,

```
SELECT * FROM NextLesson 
WHERE LessonID = @MyLesson 
AND QualifyingMinScore <= @MyScore 
AND @MyScore <= QualifyingMaxScore
```

Cheers,
Eric

Comment: That's a great idea.  I also could have merged the fields into the Lesson table, since it's essentially a one-to-one relation, but I didn't want to clutter the Lesson table and complicate its update queries.  It was set up as it is simply because its easy to view and populate the data right in SQL Server Management Studio, since it resembled the spreadsheet from which the data originated.  Anyway, your solution is probably the best one possible, and it allows the scores to be explicitly specified and flexible per-lesson.  I guess there's nothing I can do about SQL Server's limitations.

Answer (score 4):

You can't have more than one cascading RI link to a single table in any given linked table.  [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321843) explains this:

> You receive this error message because
>   in SQL Server, a table cannot appear
>   more than one time in a list of all
>   the cascading referential actions that
>   are started by either a DELETE or an
>   UPDATE statement. For example, the
>   tree of cascading referential actions
>   must only have one path to a
>   particular table on the cascading
>   referential actions tree.

Comment: I understood what the error was, I just don't understand why they implemented the cycle detection so simplistically that it incorrectly states that my link "may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths", when it can be shown through a directed dependency graph that it would not cause any such cycles.  The implementation Microsoft uses doesn't seem to consider the direction of the relationship or the dependencies, so it doesn't detect real cycles, but rather their possibility.  Perhaps it's implemented that way because of the possibility of triggers running or something...