# ON UPDATE CASCADE with two columns in a single table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-update, foreign-key-relationship

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'c_name' on table 't_name' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803836/introducing-foreign-key-constraint-c-name-on-table-t-name-may-cause-cycles-or)

I have a person table

```
    person_id   name
    1           John
    2           Josh
```

I have a relationship table

```
   relationship_id  person_a  person_b
   1                1         2
```

I am creating a foreign key relationship between relationship.person_a -> person.person_id with ON UPDATE CASCADE. This works fine. Now I try to create a foreign key relationship between relationship.person_a -> person.person_id with UPDATE CASCADE, but I get an error from SQL Server as follows:

```
SQL ALTER TABLE [dbo].[relationship] ADD CONSTRAINT [person_b_is_person] FOREIGN KEY ([person_b]) REFERENCES [dbo].[person] ([person_id]) ON UPDATE CASCADE:

Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'person_b_is_person' on table 'relationship' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
```

Why is this a problem?? Works on other databases like MySQL, Postgres. I want the ON UPDATE CASCADE so that if the person_id is changed, the relationships should be updated with the correct ids as well.

Comment: also answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/851625/foreignkey-constraint-may-cause-cycles-or-multiple-cascade-paths)

Comment: It is also useful to note that such multiple cascade paths although allowed, is also not good for MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

<blockquote>
Between two tables, you should not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.
</blockquote>